# Libragnar(Libtorrent Wrapper) LocalTorrent File, Instead of URL? C#/C++

Tags: c#, c++, libtorrent

**Question:**
Does anyone know how to add a torrent to [LibRagnar](https://github.com/libragnar/ragnar) using a filepath to a torrent, instead of a Url? (LibRagnar is a libtorrent Wrapper)
libragnar = C#
libtorrent = C++

Alternatively if anyone knows How I can use Libtorrent To add the torrent to a session, But use a local file (Whilst still controlling Everything else using Libragnar).But I am not sure where to start with Libtorrent.

---

**Reason For Problem:**
I have to use a filepath because the Torrent Requires cookie login to access it. So I either Need to get Libragnar to use a CookieCollection when getting a torrent from a URL or make it use a local ".torrent" file.

---

**Problem:**
I am currently trying to use a filepath instead of URL and the Torrent Status gives an error:`unsupported URL protocol: D:\Programming\bin\Debug\Tempfiles\File.torrent`. Which wont allow me to start it.

Example:

```
    var addParams = new AddTorrentParams
{
    SavePath = "C:\\Downloads",
    Url = "D:\\Programming\\bin\\Debug\\Tempfiles\\File.torrent"
};
```

---

### Edit: Answer from Tom W (Posted in C# Chatroom)

```
var ati = new AddTorrentParams()
{
    TorrentInfo = new TorrentInfo("C:\thing.torrent"),
    SavePath = @"C:\save\"
};
```

---

Note About Answer: I attempted to edit Tom W's post and add the answer he gave me in the Chatroom, However I guess it got declined? But Since he was the one who helped me I wanted him to get credit, and also wanted anyone else having this issue, to have an answer. So I had to add the answer to the bottom of my question.

Comment: If someone could at least point me in the direction to solve this problem, at least then Maybe I can answer it myself later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [libtorrent documentation](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/manual.html#async-add-torrent-add-torrent) it appears that:

> The only mandatory parameters are save_path which is the directory
>   where you want the files to be saved. You also need to specify either
>   the ti (the torrent file), the info_hash (the info hash of the
>   torrent) or the url (the URL to where to download the .torrent file
>   from)

Libragnar's [AddTorrentParams](https://github.com/libragnar/ragnar/blob/0f21cc4fd64e1983338fd313a97d9ecd794df77b/src/Ragnar/AddTorrentParams.cpp) appears to be a wrapper around `add_torrent_params` and has a property called `TorrentInfo`. I suspect if you avoid setting the URL, and set this property to an instance of `TorrentInfo` instead, you ought to get the result you want.

Disclaimer: I've never worked with torrents before, don't know this library, and don't work in C++.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to figure out how to directly access the libtorrent library when I'm only using Libragnar. I've only delved into C++ a small amount (recreated space invaders for the 3ds (homebrew), never got it finished though).

Anyway I will probably have to modify the AddTorrentParams of Libragnar or Use Libtorrent directly. (Which I want to avoid desperately) Thanks for pointing me in the direction at least, Now I know which Methods to look into.